# Help identifying weed in lawn

Tags: identification, weeds

I've got this weed that started in the far corner of my lawn, and is making its way into the middle of the yard. It's the heart-shaped plant in the picture below. I'm in the Boston area. I appreciate any help you can give me.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

That looks like a violet - possibly the common wood violet, given your location. No herbicides totally kill it, so your best hope of eliminating it from your lawn is to manually dig it up. I use a garden knife (also called a hori-hori) - this makes it much easier to dig than a trowel or shovel.